# How to convert json array to java script using php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this data...

```
    {"quiz":
      [{"question":"What is your favorite color?",
        "choices":[{"prefix":"A","content":"Red"},{"prefix":"B","content":"Blue"},{"prefix":"C","content":"Yellow"},{"prefix":"D","content":"Pink"}]},
       {"question":"What is the equivalent measurement of 1 feet?",
        "choices":[{"prefix":"A","content":"12cm"},{"prefix":"B","content":"12px"},{"prefix":"C","content":"12mm"},{"prefix":"D","content":"12inch"}]},
        {"question":"What is the combination of Green?",
        "choices":[{"prefix":"A","content":"Yellow and Red"},{"prefix":"B","content":"Blue and Orange"},{"prefix":"C","content":"Yellow and Blue"},{"prefix":"D","content":"Black and Skyblue"}]}],"success":1}
```

and i want to convert it in java script like this one...

```
       const myQuestions = [
  {
  question: "Who is the strongest?",
  answers: {
    a: "Superman",
    b: "The Terminator",
    c: "Waluigi, obviously"
  },
  correctAnswer: "c"
},
{
  question: "What is the best site ever created?",
  answers: {
    a: "SitePoint",
    b: "Simple Steps Code",
    c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
  },
  correctAnswer: "c"
},
{
  question: "Where is Waldo really?",
  answers: {
    a: "Antarctica",
    b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
    c: "Sitting in a tree",
    d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
  },
  correctAnswer: "d"
}
   ];
```

how can I achieve this one, because im making a quiz app which will view in mobile device by the use of webviewer. any help is much appreciated..

Comment: const myQuestions = JSON.parse("{json}");

Comment: How does one determine what could be a `correctAnswer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start of how you could potentially convert the array. Be aware, there is no correctAnswer column in your input, so it's impossible to convert:

```js
var input = {"quiz":
      [{"question":"What is your favorite color?",
        "choices":[{"prefix":"A","content":"Red"},{"prefix":"B","content":"Blue"},{"prefix":"C","content":"Yellow"},{"prefix":"D","content":"Pink"}]},
       {"question":"What is the equivalent measurement of 1 feet?",
        "choices":[{"prefix":"A","content":"12cm"},{"prefix":"B","content":"12px"},{"prefix":"C","content":"12mm"},{"prefix":"D","content":"12inch"}]},
        {"question":"What is the combination of Green?",
        "choices":[{"prefix":"A","content":"Yellow and Red"},{"prefix":"B","content":"Blue and Orange"},{"prefix":"C","content":"Yellow and Blue"},{"prefix":"D","content":"Black and Skyblue"}]}],"success":1}
        
console.log(input.quiz.map(({question, choices}) => ({
  question,
  answers: choices.reduce((obj, v) => Object.assign(obj, {[v.prefix]: v.content}), {}),
  correctAnswer: "?",
})));
```

Comment: sir please, can you make it dynamic like from php json_array to java var. thank a lot.

Comment: in my script I add the code you give with this...<script type="text/javascript">
  function output(){
     var input = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($json_array); ?>'); ...because the above json array is fetch in database.